# Foreach to return Model.Roles is failing with null reference exception

Tags: entity-framework, authorization, roles

I am trying to implement roles in an EF application. I have it working on all the scaffolded views (Create, Delete, Details) but am having trouble getting the `Edit` view to work.

The `GET` method returns the data fine (as in when I go to the Edit page I see the roles correctly):

[image]
However, if I make a change and save it, I get the error:

> **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
>   Line 47: @Html.Label("Roles", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
>   Line 48: < span class="col-md-10" >
>   Line 49: @foreach (var item in Model.RolesList)
>   Line 50: {
>   Line 51: < input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRole" value="@item.Value"
>    checked="@item.Selected" class="checkbox-inline" />

My `Get` and `Post` methods are as follows:

```
//
// GET: /Users/Edit/1
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var userRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);

    return View(new EditUserViewModel()
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        Email = user.Email,
        Username = user.UserName,
        FirstName = user.FirstName,
        LastName = user.LastName,

        RolesList = RoleManager.Roles.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Selected = userRoles.Contains(x.Name),
            Text = x.Name,
            Value = x.Name
        })

    });
}

//
// POST: /Users/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Email,Id,Username,FirstName,LastName")] EditUserViewModel editUser, params string[] selectedRole)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(editUser.Id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        user.UserName = editUser.Username;
        user.Email = editUser.Email;
        user.FirstName = editUser.FirstName;
        user.LastName = editUser.LastName;

        var userRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);

        selectedRole = selectedRole ?? new string[] { };

        var result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, selectedRole.Except(userRoles).ToArray<string>());

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
            return View();
        }
        result = await UserManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user.Id, userRoles.Except(selectedRole).ToArray<string>());

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
            return View();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something failed.");
    return View();
}
```

and the offending section in my View is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Roles", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <span class="col-md-10">
        @foreach (var item in Model.RolesList)
        {
            <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRole" value="@item.Value" checked="@item.Selected" class="checkbox-inline" />
            @Html.Label(item.Value, new { @class = "control-label" })
        }
    </span>
</div>
```

I have the `rolemanager` set up in my controller:

```
private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;
public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
{
    get
    {
        return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _roleManager = value;
    }
}
```

And this is in my `Startup.auth`:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
```

I'm pretty confident the `rolemanager` is set up OK, as it successfully brings back the roles on the `Create` and `Details` pages. So why is

```
@foreach (var item in Model.RolesList)
```

failing with a null reference exception here?

Comment: try to use @html.checkboxfor()

Comment: can you post your full view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few steps you can take

You should pass the model on your return View to load the view again with ModelState errors.

```
return View(editUser);
```

If you are using c#6 or up, then you can take take the advantage of [`null-conditional operator`](https://csharp.today/c-6-features-null-conditional-and-and-null-coalescing-operators/) to avoid  `null reference exception` on the following line

```
@foreach (var item in Model?.RolesList)
```

#### Updated

I am just adding the control flow of your error "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**"
If you add a break-point on your `ModelState.IsValid` on the `[HttpPost]`, you may notice your `ModelState.IsValid` is false. For this reason it is trying to go to the view but you haven't  send your model on the last line of the method which is `return View();`. And now the view get `null` reference into Model. And finally, it boom on the line `foreach (var item in Model.RolesList)`

So check, what errors you are getting on ModelState, model validation is unsuccessful

Comment: Cheers @MJK, and sorry for the radio silence (been away with no internet connection). The issue was due to the ModelState validation failing because the model was expecting a password. Added ModelState.Remove("Password") before the validation and it's all good now.

Answer (score 1):

The Edit [HttpPost] method doesn't return the model:

```
return View();
```

should be

```
return View(editUser);
```

Also, you'll need to make sure `editUser` contains a `selectedRole` property, or you'll get the same (or similar) error.

Otherwise, create and return a new `EditUserViewModel` object as you have done in the Get method.